# Can a C++11 program use BlueZ?

Tags: c++, c++11, bluetooth, bluez

I am having trouble compiling a simple C++11 program using the BlueZ library :

```
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
int main() {}
```

Compiling this with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` on my Fedora 21 box gives :

```
In file included from ../scale.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/bluetooth/bluetooth.h: In function ‘uint64_t bt_get_le64(const void*)’:
/usr/include/bluetooth/bluetooth.h:177:9: error: expected identifier before ‘*’ token
  return bt_get_unaligned((const uint64_t *) ptr);
         ^
...
```

This is with BlueZ version 5.23 and GCC 4.9.2. Everything works if I remove the `-std=c++11` flag.

Is this normal?

Comment: There is no gcc 5.9.2. It works fine on debian with the same version of bluez and gcc-4.9.2.

Comment: Thanks @sjdowling and @MarcGlisse . The GCC version is fixed and ```-std=gnu++11``` compiles just fine. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default GCC compiles to C++03 with GNU extensions. If you specify `-std=C++11` then it compiles to ISO C++11 with no extensions enabled. However if you specify `-std=gnu++11` instead then you also get the GNU extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in bluetooth.h, just replace `typeof` with `__typeof__` and this will be fixed, here's a reference: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/lib/bluetooth.h?id=cf52a40302d0d20ccca22a7a1f53e46ef8abfca8