# How to implement serial-communication via bluetooth in c++ on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, serial-communication, rfcomm

I am planning to write two programs in c++ (IDE is VS2019 Community) which is sending data to a raspberry pi 3 (Windows Iot).

So one program is on a computer and sending data, and the second program is running on the raspberry pi and reserving the data (and sending instructions to an CNC-board (tmcm 6110)but that already works). So now the point is, that I have absolute no clue, how to manage Bluetooth in c++.

The problem is, that I have absolute no clue, how to manage Bluetooth in c++.

Comment: [Bluetooth API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-programming-with-windows-sockets) or use thirdparty lib, 32feet (.NET) or [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) (C++)

Comment: Starting places for you.  https://github.com/mbientlab/Warble as well as https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831171/bluetooth-library-cross-platform-in-c as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925454/can-a-c11-program-use-bluez